# watchify cannot find module error

Tags: npm, browserify, watchify

I am attempting to use watchify on the command line, this is the command im using

```
watchify ./app/static_src/js/*.js -o ./app/static/js/compiled.js -v -d
```

It produces the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/repos/myapp/app/static_src/js/*.js' from '/home/user/repos/myapp/app'
```

I have also tried it with absolute paths and got the same error.